# ARC extension return data but how to implement in php code

Tags: php, web-services, rest

//I have used this code but returning blank and what data to pass in $data array.I share you all detail here.
http://dev.hordanso.com:5050
merchant=justenergy&username=mogobahor&password=VerJust123&method=GetHistory

```
 $method='POST';

$url='http://dev.hordanso.com:5050';

$data=array("headers"=>"GetHistory","Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","name"=>"JustEnergyAPI-AlphaBills","payload"=>"merchant=justenergy&method=GetNextPayment","kind"=>"ARC#RequestData");

CallAPI($method, $url, $data);

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }
    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "mogobahor:VerJust123");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

}
?>
```